# my touchpad and keyboard in labptop is notworking in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, laptop, touchpad

i am using dell inspiron n5110 , in this touch pad and keyboard is not working in Ubuntu 13.04, but it is perfectly working in the window

Answer (score 0):

To get the touch pad working try the following.

Try the following

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
>
> synclient TouchpadOff=0
>
> sudo chmod +wrx '/var/lib/dpkg/lock'
>
> sudo apt-get install synaptic

For the keyboard try the following to check if the keyboard is defined

> xinput list

For more details refer to the following link

[12.04 Touchpad not working Asus g51vx-A1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967228&page=2&s=62c66755419894eab84d354649d1ea2b)