# How can I fix the touchpad on my Chromebook 14 using Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, chromebook

I did a fresh install. Still, neither `dmesg | grep mouse` nor `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` seem to show any input from a touchpad.

I am still looking for a way to fix the touchpad. Any help has been and will be greatly appreciated.

================================================================================
When I initially installed Ubuntu, the touchpad worked just fine. After doing some updates, the touchpad quit working.

I followed these [instructions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1308264/comments/9)
but that failed to fix the problem.

`lsmod | grep psmouse` produces `psmouse 109109 0`

`psmouse.conf` does not seem to exist in `/etc/modprobe.d`

Neither `dmesg | grep mouse` nor `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` seem to [show](http://pastebin.com/r9KRcs3i) that the touchpad is a valid input.

The following suggeested solution failed :

```
    sudo modprobe -r psmouse
    sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics gpointing-device-settings` and trying the above solution did not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the output from the following commands, 'xinput list" and "lsmod | grep psmouse"

Comment: ⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]

I could not find "lsmod | grep psmouse"

Comment: So looks like the module is no getting loaded. Try the following two commands "sudo modprobe -r psmouse" "sudo modprobe psmouse"

Comment: I followed both commands. The touchpad is still not working.

Comment: On my laptop the FN+F5 = disable/enable touch pad. Does your Chrome have such a Function key

Comment: No, I do not have a function key.

Comment: Do a "xinput query-state 4" & "xinput list-props 4" to see if the device is enabled. Also look at the following posts. http://askubuntu.com/questions/324677/my-touchpad-and-keyboard-in-labptop-is-notworking-in-ubuntu-13-04/510404#510404

Comment: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.

Also, when I executed "synclient TouchpadOff=0" I recieved "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: try this > xinput set-prop 4 "Device Enabled" 1

Comment: The touchpad is still no working."lsmod | grep psmouse" now produces "psmouse               109109  0"

Comment: Looks like the module is loaded. I suggest that you reboot. Also do a dmesg | grep mouse

Comment: I rebooted. No change.

Comment: Do a > dmesg | grep mouse

Comment: It only seems to recognize my USB mouse. http://pastebin.com/Bt1yxi8g was the output even when I unplugged the mouse.

Comment: I found thees two thread that could help you. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1308857  http://askubuntu.com/questions/483229/dell-5537-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Comment: Do you have a Elantech touch pad? If so check this link http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/

Comment: I do not have an Elantech touch pad. From running "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" I do not see any touchpad listed as an input, whether it be Elantech or Synaptics. http://pastebin.com/r9KRcs3i

Comment: The paste is not shown, for your settings in `/proc/bus/input/devices`. There is also Alps, not only Elantech and Synaptics, and it isn't necessarily going to list as "touchpad". After you run the modprobe command to stop your mouse, can you move it? If you want you can check through problems I was having with touchpad here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149049/elantech-mouse-touchpad-not-working-well

Comment: When everything else fails, two words come to resque :"wireless mouse"

Answer (score 1):

Good news!  The latest version of the Linux Kernel now supports chromebook natively and officially. No patching required.

If you are running a version before 3.17 then you need to update. Check your version.

```
uname -r
```

To update manually, run the following (64-bit, 14.10 only):

```
cd /tmp
sudo mkdir kernel
cd kernel
sudo wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc1-generic_3.17.0-031700rc1.201409021903_amd64.deb
sudo wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700rc1_3.17.0-031700rc1.201409021903_all.deb
sudo wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc1-utopic/linux-image-3.17.0-031700rc1-generic_3.17.0-031700rc1.201409021903_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

**Give the boot process at least 5 minutes to finish the first time, ignore the string error you will get**

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1rsxkd/list_of_fixes_for_xubuntu_1310_on_the_acer_c720/

Answer (score 0):

maybe this page with fix is any help 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190187&p=12992534#post12992534

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I followed the instructions, does not seem to work any longer, however people were able to get it to work last month, so I wonder if perhaps it's due to more recent changes.

Comment: @tpavelka + are you sure that not a thief has stolen the little flat cable of touchpad inside your laptop ?! + or did you open the laptop with screwdriver and then the little flat cable inside is a bit "wrinkled" ?! +

Answer (score -1):

you need to install the synaptics package from here -

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

works on my Toshiba Chromebook 2.

So open terminal - Ctrl+Alt+T, type

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

and then reboot.